# Putting the default plotting theme under a texture in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, textures

I have a texture I'd like to plot over a surface, however I'd also like to retain the surfaces original coloring underneath as the texture has parts that are transparent;

[image]
[image]

How is it possible to do this? I.e. have the coloring of the first image behind the red vector field appearing on the second image instead of the one that is currently there. I've Included the plotting part of my code below for a MWE.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 1;

(*\[Alpha]=0.6;
\[Beta]=0.3;
x[u_,v_]=u;
y[u_,v_]=v;
z[u_,v_]=(\[Beta]*u^2+\[Alpha]*v^2);*)

t = Pi/2;
x[u_, v_] = Cos[t]*(Sinh [v]* Sin[ u]) + Sin[t]*(Cosh[ v]*Cos[u]);
y[u_, v_] = Cos[t]*(-Sinh [v]* Cos[ u]) + Sin[t]*(Cosh[ v]*Sin[u]);
z[u_, v_] = Cos[t]*u + Sin[t]*v;

X[u_, v_] = {x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]};

Tu[u_, v_] = D[X[u, v], u];
Tv[u_, v_] = D[X[u, v], v];
normal[u_, v_] = Simplify[Cross[Tu[u, v], Tv[u, v]]];
Tuu[u_, v_] = Simplify[D[X[u, v], {u, 2}]];
Tuv[u_, v_] = Simplify[D[X[u, v], u, v]];
Tvv[u_, v_] = Simplify[D[X[u, v], {v, 2}]];

g11[u_, v_] = Simplify[Dot[Tu[u, v], Tu[u, v]]];
g12[u_, v_] = Simplify[Dot[Tu[u, v], Tv[u, v]]];
g22[u_, v_] = Simplify[Dot[Tv[u, v], Tv[u, v]]];
h11[u_, v_] = -Simplify[Dot[Tuu[u, v], normal[u, v]]];
h12[u_, v_] = -Simplify[Dot[Tuv[u, v], normal[u, v]]];
h22[u_, v_] = -Simplify[Dot[Tvv[u, v], normal[u, v]]];

\[CapitalIota][u_, 
   v_] = {{g11[u, v], g12[u, v]}, {g12[u, v], g22[u, v]}};
\[CapitalIota]\[CapitalIota][u_, 
   v_] = {{h11[u, v], h12[u, v]}, {h12[u, v], h22[u, v]}};

Iinv[u_, v_] = Simplify[Inverse[\[CapitalIota][u, v]]];
S[u_, v_] = Iinv[u, v] . \[CapitalIota]\[CapitalIota][u, v];
Pdtangentspace[u_, v_] := Eigenvectors[S[u, v]];
Pdt1[u_, v_] := Pdtangentspace[u, v][[1]];
Pdt2[u_, v_] := Pdtangentspace[u, v][[2]];

Pd1[u_, v_] := Pdtangentspace[u, v][[1]] . {Tu[u, v], Tv[u, v]};



n = 10;
pts = Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-a, a}, {-a, a}}, 2 a/n], 1];

VF1 = VectorPlot[Pdt1[u, v], {u, -a, a}, {v, -a, a}, 
   VectorStyle -> {Red}, VectorColorFunction -> None, 
   VectorSizes -> 2, VectorPoints -> pts, Frame -> None] // Image


Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, -a, a}, {v, -a, 
    a}, PlotStyle -> {Texture[VF1]},
   PlotRange -> Full, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large
   ]
  ] // Image
ParametricPlot3D[{x[u, v], y[u, v], z[u, v]}, {u, -a, a}, {v, -a, 
   a}] // Image
```

Comment: The image in `Texture[image]` paints the surface to which the texture is applied.  Try making the background of the image the same as the desired style of the plot.